# Get error while editing Customers from back end in Magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, e-commerce

I suddenly started encountering this error out of no where and need some help.

In my Manage Customers section, when ever I add a new customer, it shows up fine with all values correct. But whenever I try to edit a newly added customer I get an error page in Magento.

> There has been an error processing your request.

And later when I return to 'Manage Customers' grid, the 'Customer Since' column for that customer record changes to this value "30 Nov -1 01:00:00"

So does any one have any idea what might be going wrong over there?

This is the error in var/report folder,

```
a:5:{i:0;s:25:"No date part in '' found.";i:1;s:4432:"#0 /home/wpfsl/public_html/lib/Zend/Date.php(1078): Zend_Date->_calculate('set', false, NULL, 'en_GB')
#1 /home/wpfsl/public_html/lib/Zend/Date.php(197): Zend_Date->set(false, NULL, 'en_GB')
#2 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php(478): Zend_Date->__construct(false, NULL, Object(Zend_Locale))
#3 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View.php(76): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->date(false)
#4 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View->getCreateDate()
#5 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/wpfsl/pub...')
#6 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#7 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#8 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#9 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#10 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(303): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#11 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml(38): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View))
#12 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/wpfsl/pub...')
#13 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#14 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#15 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#17 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#19 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#21 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#22 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/wpfsl/pub...')
#23 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#24 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#25 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#27 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#28 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#29 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php(151): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#30 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController->editAction()
#31 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#32 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#33 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(347): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#34 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#35 /home/wpfsl/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#36 {main}";s:3:"url";s:80:"/index.php/wpfsl_admin/customer/edit/id/11/key/4e2ec034dd470035e31f5f55242e0811/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

---

Sorry I also realized that though the code I wrote atleast lets me edit my records without any error but still changes the Customer Since to a random date value like 30 No -01 01:00:00.

But also if I try to create an order from the back end for a customer also created using the back end of magento, I get the following error

`a:5:{i:0;s:825:"Invalid method Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_History::isCustomerNotificationNotApplicable(Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Pending
            [notified] => 0
            [comment] => 
            [created_at] => Zend_Date Object
                (
                    [_locale:Zend_Date:private] => en_GB
                    [_fractional:Zend_Date:private] => 0
                    [_precision:Zend_Date:private] => 3
                    [_unixTimestamp:Zend_Date_DateObject:private] => 1323946274
                    [_timezone:Zend_Date_DateObject:private] => Europe/London
                    [_offset:Zend_Date_DateObject:private] => -3600
                    [_syncronised:Zend_Date_DateObject:private] => 0
                    [_dst:protected] => 1
                )`

```
    )
```

)
)";i:1;s:4197:"#0 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/history.phtml(38): Varien_Object->__call('isCustomerNotif...', Array)


    `#1 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/history.phtml(38): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_History->isCustomerNotificationNotApplicable(Array)
    #2 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/wpfsl/pub...')
    #3 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
    #4 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
    #5 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #6 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #7 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(303): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #8 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml(38): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_History))
    #9 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/wpfsl/pub...')
    #10 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
    #11 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
    #12 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #13 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #14 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #15 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
    #16 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #17 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
    #18 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
    #19 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/wpfsl/pub...')
    #20 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
    #21 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
    #22 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #23 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #24 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #25 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
    #26 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(119): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
    #27 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->viewAction()
    #28 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
    #29 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #30 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(347): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #31 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #32 /home/wpfsl/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #33 {main}";s:3:"url";s:88:"/index.php/wpfsl_admin/sales_order/view/order_id/3/key/148f59cc3e6d14da7c22a004114985cf/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}`

Again I am guessing this error has also got something to do with the Date factor?

Comment: Oh I have just realised, the customers I had before today are getting edited fine. Only the customers I have started adding from today either by using backend's "Add New Customer" or using front end interface. I am not able to edit them n their 'Customer since' changes to '30 Nov -1 01:00:00' once I try to edit them.

Comment: Please post the appropriate error message (should`ve been dumped to your `var/report` folder).

Comment: I have edited the question with the error message form var/report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as though this is a bug in Magento related to the date formats in different locales. When editing a customer the created_at field is editable and displayed in the current locale. For me being in the UK this was DD/MM/YYYY. When clicking save it attempts to put this value directly into the database and fails because its not an acceptable database format.

I have fixed this by adding the following function to Mage_Customer_Model_Form. A much better solution would be to create a class rewrite. An even better solution would be for Magento to pass through any fields which are converted using locale and then convert them back to the iso format before trying to insert these back into the database. Without this feature (and maybe its there already I dont know) this problem is very likely to recur as far as I can see.

```
public function compactData(array $data)
{
    if (array_key_exists('created_at', $data))
    {
        $data['created_at'] = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($data['created_at'])->getIso();
    }

    return parent::compactData($data);
}
```

EDIT:

Done some more digging. I noticed that the dob field is working fine. This is because the field itself is set up with all the correct bits to tell the datepicker to send back a date in the MM/DD/YYYY format.

It seems Magento is set up to handle this problem in a number of ways. There is an unused function _filterPostData() in the CustomerController which calls _filterDates() which does a better job (I assume) than my solution above.

I have changed my fix to use this function, although it has to be called from the controller scope. Again, I dont advise changing core code, but my new fix is in Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController::saveAction(). I have added the second of these lines:

```
$formData   = $customerForm->extractData($this->getRequest(), 'account');
$formData   = $this->_filterDates($formData, array('created_at')); /// added this line
```

Answer (score 2):

I have this issue too, but I found the way to change it without any coding.
First of all if you get this error, it is caused by the date setting, Magento 1.6 and EE1.11 started updating their database model to be able to use Oracle and other SQL DB. This is why they need to change the database table type from `datetime` to `timestamp` as it can simply be parsed by the database itself. The following is the solution:

1. Firstly, if you have this error, you need to go to the database to update the `customer_entity` table. Search the `created_at` field, if it is empty give it a valid value, I am so shocked that Magento now allows you to edit `created_at` date in admin, don't know how useful it will be.
2. After that, you will get the correct date and you can view the admin customer edit form. As my site is built on EE1.11, it should be same as 1.6.0 or 1.6.1. I was using AU as default locale so that is where the errors were coming from.
   You must go to `Configuration` -> `Catalog` -> `Date & Time Custom Options` and make sure it is using AU format `DD/MM/YYY` and if this is done before your site goes live, it should be fine.

Hope this help, as most developers will not go through all the settings before they start coding. Cheers!

Ben Zhang

Answer (score 2):

As per Oscar Reales post above, changing the `created_at` attribute `backend_model` in the `eav_attribute` table fixed my problem, however the value I used was the same as the dob one

```
eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime
```

That worked for me and entering 31/10/2012 showed correct, the `eav/entity_attribute_backend_time_created` resulted in the random date thing above. I have tested this by editing an existing accounts created at date, created an account in the backend and created an account in the frontend. All worked fine. Btw, my locale is UK.

Answer (score 1):

Struggling with the same kind of problem here.
So i've tried it on a clean install of Magento 1.6.1.0 and the following happens.

1. Create customer at frontend
2. record in table "Customer Entity" contains column created_at with value = **2011-12-15 10:14:45**
3. In admin > customer > manage customers > edit customer and click save
4. record in table "Customer Entity" value of *created_at* changed to **2015-12-11 00:00:00**

Answer (score 1):

As I stated before, you can do this attribute backend_model update using a custom module, and adding this line to the setup script:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->getAttribute('created_at')
  ->setBackendModel('eav/entity_attribute_backend_time_created')
  ->setAttributeModel(new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL'))
  ->setInputFilter('date')
  ->save();
```

Comment: Hi there, you dint specify which file needs this edit to be made? And will this edit alone save the date in proper format and restrain from giving any errors?

Comment: It would be great if any one could come and reply so as to where the above change needs to be made (i.e.e which file) and does this edit solve the problem?

Comment: I would really appreciate if you explain your solution in detail so that I can try and work that out for my code as well. Right now its too vague for me to understand so as to what files needs what editing, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Magento 1.6.x (you didn't mention the version), lines #3 and #4 of your report

```
#3 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View.php(76): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->date(false)
#4 /home/wpfsl/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View->getCreateDate()
```

indicate, that your customers `created_at` field<sup>*****</sup> does *not* contain a valid datetime/timestamp:

```
public function getCreateDate()
{
    $date = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($this->getCustomer()->getCreatedAtTimestamp());
    return $this->formatDate($date, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM, true);
}
```

Note that `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View` fails to format an **already existing** (but invalid) value of the `created_at` field.

Your *real* problem is somewhere else, earlier in the records lifecycle.

I'd start off checking whether adding of a new customer really produces valid `created_at` entries.

---

<sub>*`customer_since` is only a virtual mapping of `created_at`</sub> .

Comment: Yes it indeed creates right entries when the customer is first created. And the date values stay fine unless we edit the record. As soon as we edit the record the value changes to a random date and 0000:00:00 00:00:00 in database. Also while creating the order, it throws an error which I have mentioned below and never really proceeds ahead.

Comment: When you edit the record, which action is called exactly, to save the edited data (class::method() please)? And please show the date being passed along the form submission which requests that save action.

Comment: I am not sure about this, but the layout for it is being created in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit.php and the actual save and edit action is happening in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php::saveAction(),i guess. But I am not sure.

Comment: And I am sorry I dint get you when you say, 'And please show the date being passed along the form submission which requests that save action.'

Comment: I am still facing the same problems and its for all of my store with Magento 1.6.0 n 1.6.1 Please help and let me know if there is a fix for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Magento ve 1.6.1. My getCreateDate() function is exactly as you have mentioned. I don't see a problem there, coz the date does get saved properly when a new customer is created. It only changes when I edit my records.

Found a partial solution. Changing lib/Zend/Date.php with this code lets me edit and save my records fine without giving any error.

```
isset($parsed['year']) ? (1970 + $parsed['year']) : 1970,
                        false), $this->getUnixTimestamp(), false);

                } catch (Zend_Locale_Exception $e) {

/*-- fix BEGIN --*/Zend_Locale_Format::getDate( ) failed --*/

                    if( !is_numeric( $date ) ) {

                            $parsed = date_parse( $date . ( $locale != "" ? " " . $locale : "" ) );
                            if( $parsed === FALSE ) {
                                    $parsed = array( 'year' => 1970, 'month' => 1, 'day' => 1, 'hour' => 0, 'minute' => 0, 'second' => 0 );
                            }

                            return $this->_assign( $calc, $this->mktime(
                                            $parsed['hour'],
                                            $parsed['minute'],
                                            $parsed['second'],
                                            $parsed['month'],
                                            $parsed['day'],
                                            $parsed['year'], false ),
                                            $this->getUnixTimestamp( ), false );

                    } else {

                            #require_once 'Zend/Date/Exception.php';
                            throw new Zend_Date_Exception( $e->getMessage( ) , 0, $e, $date );
                    }
/*-- fix END --*/

                }

            }

            return $this->_assign($calc, $date, $this->getUnixTimestamp(), false);
            break;
```

But when ever I edit any newly added customer record, the Customer Since changes back to 30 Nov -1 01:00:00. So is this is a known bug or what? does any one have any work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the backend_model used by this attribute. dob uses "eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime" backend_model, and product is using "eav/entity_attribute_backend_time_created" but created_at for customer is not using it. This backend_model is handling all the conversion and filter dates, so, it is so simple as changing the "eav_attribute" table. Search for the attribute_code = 'created_at' AND entity_type_id = 1 and update the value of the backend_model from NULL to "eav/entity_attribute_backend_time_created" and that is. No core files needs to be changed.

If you prefer, you can use a Resource Setup to update this attribute from the installer of your own module.